# If and Elseif not working right

Tags: powershell, active-directory

For the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm sure I'm not understanding the last elseif statement properly with contains, but every example I've read tells me I'm doing it right.

This script I wrote first checks to see if a parent group contains a child group, if not it adds the group and the does a final check and outputs "Yes" or "No" depending if the group nesting occurred or not.

But for whatever the reason the output is always "No", even if the group nesting has occurred. When I look at the parent group in AD I see the child group added, when I look at user3.txt I see the child group name "bathroom" inside the text file.. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $group = "bathroom"
    $validate = Get-ADGroupMember -identity BuildingGroups | format-table -HideTableHeaders "name" | out-file .\bathroom\user.txt -Append
    $validate2 = get-content .\bathroom\user.txt
    $Dest = ".\bathroom\user.txt"
    $childgroup = Get-ADGroup $childgroupOU
    $parentgroup = Get-ADGroup $parentgroupOU

If (Select-String -Path $Dest -Pattern $group) {
    Write-Host "$group is already a member of BuildingGroups."
}

elseif ($validate2 -notcontains $group) {

    try {
    Add-ADGroupMember $parentgroup –Member $childgroup –Server "$prefix.$root.ca"
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity BuildingGroups | format-table -HideTableHeaders "name" | out-file .\bathroom\user2.txt -Append
    }
    catch {
    $_.Exception | out-file .\bathroom\addgroup_error.txt -Append
    }

}
    (gc .\bathroom\user2.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content .\bathroom\user3.txt
    $validate4 = Get-Content .\bathroom\user3.txt

If ($validate4 -contains $group) {
    Write-Host "Yes"
}
elseif ($validate4 -notcontains $group) {
    Write-Warning "No"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `$user3.txt`

Comment: bathroom                                                                                                                              
toilet                                                                                                                                      
bide (note that each group is on its own line inside the file user3.txt)

Comment: Did you checked the output of `$validate4`?

Comment: Yes I did, `$validate4` simply outputs what's inside the `user3.txt` which contains the `bathroom` group I'm checking for. Yet even when `user3.txt` contains the `bathroom` group i still get a response of `No`.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce when I create the txt file using your provided content - I get `Yes` outputed...

Comment: How bizarre, thank you for the assistance Martin.

Comment: Make sure theres no spurious whitespace in the file (like spaces after a name). Also check the encoding of the file.

Comment: Whitespaces wasn't the issue. My logic was wrong, I added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $group = "bathroom"
        $validate = Get-ADGroupMember -identity BuildingGroups | format-table -HideTableHeaders "name" | out-file .\bathroom\user.txt -Append
        $validate2 = get-content .\bathroom\user.txt
        $Dest = ".\bathroom\user.txt"
        $childgroup = Get-ADGroup $childgroupOU
        $parentgroup = Get-ADGroup $parentgroupOU

    If (Select-String -Path $Dest -Pattern $group) {
        Write-Host "$group is already a member of BuildingGroups."
    }

    elseif ($validate2 -notcontains $group) {

        try {
        Add-ADGroupMember $parentgroup –Member $childgroup –Server "$prefix.$root.ca"
        Get-ADGroupMember -identity BuildingGroups | format-table -HideTableHeaders "name" | out-file .\bathroom\user2.txt -Append
        }
        catch {
        $_.Exception | out-file .\bathroom\addgroup_error.txt -Append
        }

    }

    $containsWord = Get-Content .\bathroom\user2.txt | %{$_ -match $group}

    If ($containsWord -contains $true) {
        Write-Host "Yes"
    }
    elseif ($validate4 -notcontains $group) {
        Write-Warning "No"
    }
```

Comment: The final if statement seems a bit wonky there?